# Visual Studio C++ 2010 in-project link error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lnk2019

I have a multi-file project in VSC++2010, but for some reason it won't link some of them properly.

For example, I have CParser.h and CParser.cpp . CParser.h is just some function declarations:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

void parseArg(int argc, char* argv[], GVar gv);
void parseCfg(string cfg, GVar gv)
```

CParser.cpp just contains implementations:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "_GlobalVar.h" //defines GVar, not relevant
#include "CParser.h"

void parseArg(int argc, char* argv[], GVar &gv) {
    /*not really relevant*/
}
```

And the error:

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   parseArg(int,char * * const,class GVar)"
>   (?parseArg@@YAXHQAPADVGVar@@@Z) referenced in function _SDL_main

Edit:

There's also this other problem:

```
template<class T>
void RDAMHandler<T>::clean() {
    long i;
    while(!avtick.empty())
        avtick.pop();
    for(i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        delete all[i];
        all.pop_back();
        v.pop_back();
    }
}
```

And the declaration:

```
template<class T>
class RDAMHandler {
    vector<T*> all;
    priority_queue<long> avtick;
    vector<bool> v;
public:
    T &operator[](long x);
    long insert(T &x);
    void del(long x);
    void clean();
};
```

I don't see any difference here; what is the problem?

Edit edit: And error

> main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall RDAMHandler::clean(void)" (?clean@?$RDAMHandler@USDL_Surface@@@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function
>   "void __cdecl cleanUp(class GVar)" (?cleanUp@@YAXVGVar@@@Z)

Comment: To track these things down next time from the name the linker gives, use `undname`, which comes with Visual Studio (i.e. use the VS command prompt), the `C++ Name Undecorator`.

Comment: please Check if your `.h` file is included in `VCProject`. For that Check in `Solution Explorer` Pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **CParser.cpp**

I think You have to use statement

`void CParser::parseArg(int argc, char* argv[], GVar &gv)`

instead of

`void parseArg(int argc, char* argv[], GVar &gv)` in `CParser.cpp file`

And In **CParser.h**

The declaration should be changed to `void parseArg(int argc, char* argv[], GVar &gv);`

And **For Next Error**

For Reference Please  [Go through this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)
1. [Template using class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! There's still a problem, which I've edited into the original question.

Comment: I think you are using `cleanup(GVar)` in your code please check it

Comment: Hmm, no, I'm calling an instance of the class. This is what cleanup looks like:
void cleanUp(GVar gv) {
 gv.images.clean();
}
and this is how it's called:
 cleanUp(gv);

Comment: Please Try `template<class T> T void RDAMHandler<T>::clean() ` in `cpp` Hope this will help you

Comment: You can go through [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) for more reference

Comment: (sorry for not responding faster)

template<class T> T void RDAMHandler<T>::clean() gives an error (too many types); I've looked through that reference but I can't find anything that would help; also, here is the declaration of the instance that gives the error: 
 RDAMHandler<SDL_Surface> images;

Answer (score 1):

They're two different overloads - the declaration in the header has `GVar gv`, while the definition in the .cpp file has `GVar &gv`. One of these is probably a typo.